# exception during the rendering of a template ("The block type sonata.Admin.block.admin_list does not exist")

Tags: symfony, twig

**Hi**
I am new to **Symfony2** and facing this problem while generating my Admin Panel.

**An exception during the rendering of a template ("The block type sonata.Admin.block.admin_list does not exist") in SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig at line 35**

Can anyone please guide me, I'll be Grateful. I am following this documentation [Sonata Admin Bundle.](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/reference/getting_started.html)

Comment: Is Sonata Admin enabled in appkernel.php ?

Comment: Plus, when i comment the line no  35 in twig template, admin pannel appears , but there is no field to input and other features of admin pannel.

Comment: How did you solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify all blocks in app/config/config.yml:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.user.block.menu:
        sonata.user.block.account:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
```

Comment: Yes, pumpurumpum it all these are already registered in congif.yml but still i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes All these are already specified in config.yml file, still i am facing that error.
But when i comment that statement in **SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig at line 35** it works fine. i don't get any error.
Plus i am unable to get my **CRUD** functionality for my entity in admin panel, admin panel has been generate without any error.