# “The block type sonata.Admin.block.admin_list does not exist”

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata-admin

I am new to **Symfony2** and facing this problem while generating my Admin Panel.

> An exception has been occurred during the rendering of a template ("The block type sonata.Admin.block.admin_list does not exist") in SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig at line 35

I am following this documentation [Sonata Admin Bundle.](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/reference/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specify all blocks in app/config/config.yml like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164808/exception-during-the-rendering-of-a-template-the-block-type-sonata-admin-block)

```
sonata_block:
default_contexts: [cms]
blocks:
    sonata.user.block.menu:
    sonata.user.block.account:
    sonata.block.service.text:
    sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
        contexts:   [admin]
```

Answer (score 4):

I had solved this problem
You should check if you have duplicate definition of sonata_block in yout config.yml
It ste

Comment: this was my exact problem, since the tutorial tells you to add the sonata_block to the config, not replace it. Ad since I was tired i missed it but thanks for this

Comment: thx, if sonata_block defintion is twice, nothing is displayed